# Mongo aggregate using java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregate

Here is my command line code in Mongo client, But I do not know how to implement them using java sdk. Here i want to use mongoTemplate. Can someone help me?

```
db.getCollection('metrics.value').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        'serviceId': 85,
        'metricTimestamp': {
            $gte: ISODate("2018-02-03T04:33:58"),
            $lte: ISODate("2018-02-05T04:33:58")
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$metricValues", 0]
        },
        count: {
            $push: {
                $arrayElemAt: ["$metricValues", 1]
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Aggregation agg = new Aggregation( match(Criteria.where("serviceId").in(serviceId).andOperator(Criteria.where("metricTimestamp").gte(startDate), Criteria.where("metricTimestamp").lte(endDate))), group());

Comment: show us what have you tried?

Comment: Aggregation agg = new Aggregation(    match(Criteria.where("serviceId").in(serviceId).andOperator(Criteria.where("metricTimestamp").gte(startDate), Criteria.where("metricTimestamp").lte(endDate))),
    group());

Comment: I have problems with the $arrayElemAt and $push operation

Comment: Post that as part of the question